# How to clear Url cache in Browser in android programmatically?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, browser

i am going with an app, where once the button is clicked it takes you to an login page in browser. Once you have logged in, it will take you to second screen and when the user logout, it takes to the first screen, you have to login again to go the second screen. Well the problem, i am facing is once the user gets logout, it takes you to the first screen, but when you click the button it takes directly to the second screen without login screen(without getting username, password). I am stuck with it for one day and can't go further, can anyone hlep me to solve this solution.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(//url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I clear browser cash after each page with this code. May be help.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

What is your url script, anything like this below or for ever screen is the same script and zou change only some div ? I had similary problem with download PDF documents but PHP script get ever first login screen.

```
<?php
$copern = 1*$_REQUEST['copern'];
if( $copern == 0 ) { $copern=1; }
if( $copern == 1 ) { 
?>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<a href="../cis/sk2.php?copern=2" >Login</a>
<?php
               }
if( $copern == 2 ) { 
?>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<a href="../cis/sk2.php?copern=1" >Logout</a>
<?php
               }
?>
```